# How can I transfer data from one string to another and end up getting the same result?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

So I wrote this code with the help of Stack Overflow users..

```
def get_name(string):
    return string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")
def keepTabs(input_list: list):
    output = {}
    for entry in input_list:
        name = get_name(entry)
        if name not in output:
            output[name] = 0
        if "++" in entry:
            output[name] += 1
        if "--" in entry:
            output[name] -= 1
        if "->" in entry:
            output[name] == [name+1]
    return output
print(keepTabs(["Jim--", "John--", "Jordan--", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++", "June->Jim]))
```

In this code, every individual "Jim", "John" etc all start with 0 and they earn or lose points depending on where they get "--", which subtracts one away from them or "++", which adds one to their existent points...
Now I want to edit  this so that if there's a "->" provided in the list, for instance if in the list there's "John->Jim", all the points that John has, will be added to Jim's points...

I have tried to implement it as shown in the code above, but it didn't work so, what should I change to make sure this works??

**Please use the simplest version of code possible since I'm very new to this :)**

Comment: Use Split https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-string-split-and-join-methods-explained-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

My revision-

```
def get_name(string):
    return string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "")
def keepTabs(input_list: list):
    output = {}
    for entry in input_list:
        if '->' in entry:
            names = entry.split('->')
            output[names[1]] = output[names[0]]
            output[names[0]] = 0
        else:
            name = get_name(entry)
            if name not in output:
                output[name] = 0
            if "++" in entry:
                output[name] += 1
            if "--" in entry:
                output[name] -= 1
    return output
print(keepTabs(["Jim--", "John--", "Jordan--", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++", "June->Jim]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use any kind of string replacement for this. How about:

```
def keepTabs(lst):
    output = dict()
    for item in lst:
        t = item.split('->')
        if len(t) == 2:
            if t[1] in output:
                output[t[1]] += output.get(t[0], 0)
        else:
            if item.endswith('--'):
                x = -1
            elif item.endswith('++'):
                x = 1
            else:
                continue
            if (name := item[:-2]) in output:
                output[name] += x
            else:
                output[name] = x
    return output

print(keepTabs(["Jim--", "John--", "Jordan--", "Jim++", "John--", "Jeff--", "June++", "June->Jim"]))
```